# Intellij not able to run test case cucumber 4.1

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rubygems, cucumber

Recently I upgraded my cucumber version to 4.1(from 3.1.2). Now I'm not able to execute test cases from Intellij. Error is:

```
undefined method `feature' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/ast_lookup.rb:105:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/ast_lookup.rb:30:in `new'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/ast_lookup.rb:30:in `step_source'
C:/Users/demo/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/plugins/ruby/rb/testing/patch/bdd/teamcity/cucumber/cucumber_4_formatter.rb:223:in `step_node_name'
C:/Users/demo/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/plugins/ruby/rb/testing/patch/bdd/teamcity/cucumber/cucumber_4_formatter.rb:93:in `on_test_step_finished'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in `block in broadcast'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in `each'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in `broadcast'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:40:in `method_missing'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:37:in `around_hook'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/around_hook.rb:12:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in compose_around_hooks'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:81:in `compose_around_hooks'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:29:in `block in describe_to'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:19:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/filters/prepare_world.rb:11:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:57:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/filters/retry.rb:18:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/filters/quit.rb:11:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:21:in `block in done'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:20:in `map'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:20:in `done'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:20:in `done'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/tag_filter.rb:18:in `done'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/compiler.rb:31:in `done'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:46:in `done'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:35:in `parse'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:24:in `compile'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:79:in `run!'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:29:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

So because of the above error, I'm not able to execute cucumber test cases. Test cases are written in ruby.

But if I'll execute test cases like `bundle exec cucumber --name <scenario-number>` It works

How to solve this error? Is this some plugin problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue where in your hooks (Or somewhere similar), you are doing a log line or calling line for `scenario.feature.name` or something similar.

This is a known issue upgrading from v3 -> v4

Comment: So the resolution would be?

Comment: See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/issues/1432 for more information / discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "fix" this issue by commenting the following line inside \teamcity\cucumber\cucumber_4_formatter.rb step_node_name method:

`"#{@ast_lookup.step_source(test_step).step.keyword}#{test_step.text}"`

Note that you won't be able to see the names of the steps on RubyMine execution.